# Please help me solve JavaScript Asyncronus issue

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I have code in connect.js like this

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();

class Connection {

  static connect() {
    let db = new sqlite3.Database('../SQlite-tester-001/db/sqlite_tester001.db', sqlite3.OPEN_READWRITE, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
      }
      else {
        console.log('Connected to the tester database.');
      }
    });

    return db
  }
}

module.exports = Connection;
```

And I try to call it from insert.js like this

```
const Connection = require('./connect');

(async () => {
    let db = await Connection.connect();
    await console.log('This line is below Connection.connect()');
})();

console.log('This line is below Async function');
```

However, the result is not what I wanted like below

```
wittinunt@Wittinunt-VCIS-PC:~/GitHub/SQlite-tester-001$ node insert.js
This line is below Async function
This line is below Connection.connect()
Connected to the tester database.
```

What I expected it is should be like

```
Connected to the tester database.
This line is below Connection.connect()
This line is below Async function
```

**I'm very new to JavaScript** and now I very confuse about 'async-await'.

Please help.

Comment: You have 2 async functions and 3 awaits but none of them are needed.

Comment: I had deleted them all but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

There are callback/Promise/asny,await ways to handle asynchronous

And in the above code, callback and async/await are used in duplicate among the asynchronous handling methods.

The callback function works.

So delete the callback function and run.
[However, the function must support Promise]

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();

class Connection {
  static async connect() {
    try {
      let db = await new sqlite3.Database('../SQlite-tester-001/db/sqlite_tester001.db', sqlite3.OPEN_READWRITE);
      console.log('Connected to the tester database.');
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message); 
    }
  }
}

module.exports = Connection;
```

if error occrued, then "catch block" catch error.